# Proof that all elements of sequence are in $l^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

The question could be very similar, but I am new in functional analysis.

Let us consider $l^2$ space (space of square summable sequences). Next, for each fixed $j = 1, 2, \dots$ let $X^{j}_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence, such that
$$
X^{j}_{n} \to c_{j} \in \mathbb{R},
$$
as $n \to \infty$.

Next, let us assume that $c\in l^2$, i.e. the vector comprised by the limits of the sequences is in $l^2$. Also, for any finite $n$ we have that  $\{X^{j}_{n}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is in $l^2$.

**Summary:** we have a sequence of infinite dimensional vectors $\{X^{j}_{n}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$, such that each component $X^{j}_{n}$ converge to the number $c_{j}$ AND the vector $c=(c_{1}, c_{2}, \dots) \in l^{2}$ (point-wise convergence holds). Next, for all finite $n$ the vector is $\{X^{j}_{n}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ square summable.

Can we then claim that all elements of sequence $\{X^{j}_{n}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ are in $l^2$?

In another words, if the point-wise limit is in $l^{2}$ is it enough to claim the all sequence is in $l^{2}$? Note: I clearly understand, that convergence in $l^{2}$ does not follow from point-wise convergence.

**UPDATE:**  Let us take upper right triangular infinite matrix with all elements ones. For fixed $n$ all columns up to $n$ are in $l^{2}$.
Can we say that ALL columns are in $l^{2}$?

Each raw converge though... This is how I came up to this question.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading what index applies where given the notation $X_n^j$, but this looks to me like you assume that  a certain sequence is in $\ell_2$ and then ask whether it follows that it's in $\ell_2$.

Comment: Dear @DavidC.Ullrich , this is my miss-understanding and confusion. I assume that for a fixed $j$ all sequences (for each $j$) converge to the numbers $c_{i}$ and the vector $c=(c_{1}, c_{2}, \dots) \in l^{2}$. Also, for any finite $n$ the vector $X_{n}$ is in $l_{2}$. Can then I claim that for all $n$ all $X_{n}$ are in $l^{2}$.

Comment: ??? You just did it again, this time _explcitly_ asking about _exactly_ what you just assumed: "[assume that] for any finite $n$ the vector $X_n$ is in $\ell_2$. Can I then claim that for all $n$ the $X_n$ are in $\ell_2$?". This can't be the question you actually mean to ask... yes, $X_n\in\ell_2$ implies $X_n\in\ell_2$.

Comment: If I am understanding the question he is asking whether $\ell^2$ is closed under pointwise convergence. @LrM, when you write "for all $n$ all $X_n$ are in $\ell^2$", this is the same as saying that any _finite_ $n$ the sequence $X_n$ lies in $\ell^2$. I suppose what you want to ask is whether $(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n^j)_{j =1}^{\infty}$ is in $\ell^2$.

Comment: @G.Chiusole You may be right, but your hypothesis doesn't make much sense to me - if he's asking whether $\ell_2$ is closed under pointwise convergence he can't _assume_ that $c\in\ell_2$, as he does.

Comment: Indeed... I dunno

Comment: @G.Chiusole I dunno as well. Of course _he_ should really be the one to explain what he means...

Comment: I have updated the question. I apologise if my question is nonsense, probably, I am very confused with infinite dim space.

Comment: That "update" looks like you haven't bothered to read my comments. The question *still* reads "Suppose $X_n\in\ell_2$. Does it follow that $X_n\in\ell_2$?". I don't know what the problem is here, but no it has nothing to do with infinite-dimensional spaces - you're not _stating the problem_ correctly

Comment: How did you come upon this question?

Comment: Dear @BrianMoehring , look at my comment below the Answer.

Comment: Dear @DavidC.Ullrich , let us take upper right triangle infinite matrix. For fixed $n$ all columns up to $n$ are in $l^{2}$. Can we say that ALL columns are in $l^{2}$?

Comment: When in your question do you fix $n$?  And what would that even mean when $n$ is the index for your sequence?

Comment: Think of an as "row index" and $j$ is "column index"

Comment: Let me change your question to a different context.  You have written something similar to: $$\text{If } x_n \text{ is a real number for each finite } n, \\ \text{ then is } x_n \text{ a real number for every } n?$$ Do you see why this is not an interesting question?  (it's true simply by the definition of "for every")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this is **not** an answer to the question as asked. As stated above, the question asks whether P implies P. I'm giving up on getting the OP the clarify what he or she actually meant to ask; this is an answer to what I *suspect* he or she meant to ask.

Let $X_n^j=\frac1{\sqrt{jn}}$ and $c_j=0$. Then $X_n\to c$ pointwise, $c\in\ell_2$ but $X_n\notin\ell_2$.

(Not an answer to the question as asked precisely because $X_n\in\ell_2$ is a hypothesis there...)

Comment: Yes, I see. Also, one can construct the sequence such that for each fixed $n$ the vector $\{X_{n}^{(j)}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is in $l^{2}$, it converges point-wise, but to vector, which is not in $l^{2}$. For example, infinite matrix with upper right triangle all ones and lower left triangle is zeros. Then, I combine two assumptions (limit is in $l^{2}$ and square summable for any finite $n$). This is how I came up with the question.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Wasn't thinking - thanks.